# List all the directories under the current one

Tags: files-and-directories

I feel like I am forgetting something obvious, and will remember or be ashamed as soon as an answer turns up. However, I cannot for the life of me get all of the directories in the current working directory. That is, given the following folder structure:

```
a
-c
b
-c
```

I would expect

```
FileNames["*",{"*"},Infinity]
```

to return

```
{"a","b","a/c","b/c"}
```

But instead I get

```
{"a/c","b/c"}
```

I tried playing around with `Infinity` in the typical `Level`s in Mathematica (such as {1} vs. 1), but MMA complains about syntax. For the above example, how can I view a complete list of subdirectories. I came up with the following, but it doesn't seem exactly elegant:

```
RecursiveDirectory[dir_] := 
 Module[{allDirs, allDirsCheck = {}, tempDirs},
  allDirs = Select[FileNames["*"], DirectoryQ[#] &];
  While[allDirs != allDirsCheck,
   allDirsCheck = allDirs;
   tempDirs = Select[FileNames["*", allDirs], DirectoryQ[#] &];
   allDirs = Union[allDirs, tempDirs]
   ];
  allDirs
  ]
```

This function gives me:

```
In[30]:= RecursiveDirectory["*"]
Out[30]= {"a", "a\\c", "b", "b\\c"}
```

As expected. What is a nicer way of doing this?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Maybe something like

```
Select[FileNames["*", "", Infinity], DirectoryQ]
```

Comment: Thanks Heike, I didn't think of trying an empty quote. I think I tried everything but that. And I knew the answer would be very simple too....

Comment: One may also use `FileType` instead of `DirectoryQ`.

Answer (score 17):

If I'm not mistaken the second asterisk in your line

```
FileNames["*",{"*"},Infinity]
```

should be replaced with the location of the directory you want to look in.

In case of the directory where your notebook lives in this would be:

```
FileNames["*", {NotebookDirectory[]}, Infinity]
```

or, for the current directory, this would be:

```
FileNames["*", {Directory[]}, Infinity]
```

Comment: Thanks Sjoerd. +1 for a detailed answer, but according to MMA.SE, Heike answered first (post 2389 vs. 2390)

Comment: @tkott This isn't a racing contest and please don't feel obliged to accept an answer the minute it arrives. That will discourage others to add their answers.

Answer (score 14):

I recommend an external command approach.  On Windows this looks like this:

```
command = "!dir \"" <> Directory[] <> "\" /A:D /S /B";

ReadList[command, String]
```

This can be many times faster than the `Select` - `FileNames` method.

```
Select[
  FileNames["*", "C:\\Data & Images", Infinity],
  DirectoryQ
] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {6.7413856, 5693}
> ```

```
command = "!dir \"" <> "C:\\Data & Images" <> "\" /A:D /S /B";
ReadList[command, String] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.3900223, 5693}
> ```

Comment: I use `ReadList` often but had never discovered this. Good stuff! +1

Comment: @Andy thank you.  I presume you mean the ability to read command line output?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was referring to. I had a vague idea about using command line input in other places, I didn't realize it worked here as well. Potentially a very powerful idea.

Comment: @Andy yes, it's surely cleaner than having to write to a temporary file, only to `ReadList` that.  I think this should be better documented (present on the `ReadList` doc page).

Comment: You should file that as a suggestion to WRI if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

If one needs to list only *non-empty* directories, it can be easily achieved by applying `DirectoryName` to the output of `FileNames`. For example, listing all non-empty directories in `$UserBaseDirectory` up to the depth 2:

```
DeleteDuplicates[DirectoryName /@ FileNames[All, $UserBaseDirectory, 2]]
```

> ```
> {"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\", 
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\ApplicationData\\", 
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Applications\\", 
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Autoload\\", 
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\FrontEnd\\", 
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Kernel\\", 
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Knowledgebase\\", 
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\_MyStyleSheets_\\", 
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Paclets\\", 
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\SystemFiles\\"}
> ```

---

An alternative is external command approach which allows to restrict the depth of recursion.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42559986/590388) answer, starting from Windows Vista we have the `ROBOCOPY` utility as a part of the system which allows to list all subdirectories (including empty):

```
With[{dir = $UserBaseDirectory, depth = "2"}, 
 StringTrim@ImportString[
   RunProcess[{"robocopy", dir, dir, "/l", "/s", "/njh", "/njs", "/ns", "/lev:" <> depth},
     "StandardOutput"], "Lines", CharacterEncoding -> $SystemCharacterEncoding]]
```

> ```
> {"C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\", 
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\_MyStyleSheets_\\", 
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\ApplicationData\\", 
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Applications\\", 
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Autoload\\", 
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\FrontEnd\\", 
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Kernel\\", 
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Knowledgebase\\", 
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Licensing\\", 
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\Paclets\\", 
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\SearchIndices\\", 
> "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mathematica\\SystemFiles\\"}
> ```