# Calling external commands without showing command prompt on windows

Tags: interoperability, windows, external-calls

I'm playing around with some code that's calling external command-line commands on a windows platform, and when doing this, the command prompt will pop up quickly and then disappear. This is not a huge bother, if you are calling something once, however if you have a loop running and each call takes some time, it becomes a major annoyance. Consider the following code:

```
 Table[Pause[1/2]; Run[ "dir" ];, {3}];
```

Is there any way to avoid this behavior, or calling an external program though other methods then by `Run[]`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

On Windows 7 using `ReadList` instead of `Run` suppresses the window:

```
Table[Pause[1/2]; ReadList["!dir", String], {3}];
```

This use of `"!command"` in place of a file is at least partially documented under `OpenRead`:

> On systems that support pipes,`OpenRead["!command"]` runs the external
>   program specified by `command`, and opens a pipe to get input from it.

As Albert Retey notes in the comments, running a command without returning output would therefore best be done with:

```
Close @ OpenRead @ "!command"
```

And stated in Joel Klein's answer streams should always be closed.  `ReadList` does this automatically; when using `OpenRead` we must manually `Close` the stream.

Comment: The example was simply an illustration of the behavior of the problem. I'm not actually interested in the output of dir.

Comment: Yea, I'm not interested in the output, but this does solve my problem. I mistakenly though that this was calling dir specifically and not arbitrary command line code. It works perfectly however. Thank you. Do you know where the documentation for this is, I can't seem to find it under ReadList, is it a general thing that "file" and "!command" are can be interchanged when reading from streams?

Comment: @jVincent I'm glad it's working for you.  Regarding documentation I've [been asked before](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2401/121) and I still do not have a good answer.  I'm also not sure where `"!command"` can be used; I've only used `Read` and `ReadList` with it myself.

Comment: @jVincent I just realized I read your first comment backward; in light of that I suggest you use `Read["!dir", String]` as it should be a little faster; I'll update my answer with this.

Comment: `OpenRead` (and `OpenWrite`) both do support `!command`. Thus there is a good chance that functions which read or write files will understand that way to open a pipe for reading or writing as they most probably will use these functions (or lower level equivalents). I know that `Import` also supports it (surprise: that's even documented :-). The limitiation "on symstems that support pipes" seems somewhat outdated, AFAIK all systems where newer versions of Mathematica do run on support pipes.

Comment: @Albert thanks for the info.  IMHO `Import["!prog","format"] imports data from a pipe.` is not as clear as the wording under `OpenRead`; nowhere is an external command explicitly mentioned so it's easier to overlook.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I just mentioned the documentation of `!command` for `Import` because it's there, as a commitment by WRI, if you want so. I agree that the value of that sentence as a source of information is somewhat limited...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: just another note: As `OpenRead` also supports `!command`, if you don't need the output `Close[OpenRead["!command"]];` could even be more efficient...

Comment: According to documentation, if the file is already open, `ReadList` will not close it at the end.

Answer (score 21):

You can call an external (shell) command `cmd` without showing a command window by using the pipe syntax `"!"<>cmd`.  This can be used in place of a filename with any *Mathematica* function that opens a file for reading.  For example:

- `Import["!dir", "Text"]`
- `Read["!dir"]` (opens stream, must be closed)
- `OpenRead["!dir"]`, followed by `Read`, `ReadList` etc to grab the command output (opens stream, must be closed).
- `ReadList["!dir"]`
- `BinaryReadList["!dir"]`
- `Find["!dir", "tmp.txt"]` will return the first lines of cmd output containing "tmp.txt"

These functions can be found in [guide/LowLevelFileOperations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/LowLevelFileOperations.html) in the Documentation Center.

The general rules used for resolving file names are documented in the [Files and Streams](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/FilesAndStreams.html) tutorial. This is something that has had improvements for Version 9, e.g. URLs can now appear where filenames can go and the resource will be opened by making an HTTP request.

However, be alert that `OpenRead["!cmd"]` and `Read["!cmd"]` leave an open `InputStream` object, that in some cases (depending on the `cmd`) **must be closed** before a new, similar command can be run. Closing what has been opened by `Read["!dir"]` is not trivial, as `Read` does not return the `InputStream` object it opens, so one has to check `Streams[]`. In some cases (again, depending on `cmd`), an `InputStream["!cmd"]` object might not be closable (*Mathematica* hangs) as the running process must be killed via `taskkill`, the Task Manager or similar. Furthermore, commands that start permanent processes (unlike `dir` that is terminated immediately) can cause *Mathematica* to wait until the process is closed outside of *Mathematica*, e.g.:

```
ReadList["!notepad.exe"]
Print["next"]
```

the `Print` statement is not evaluated and *Mathematica* does not continue until the appearing Notepad window is closed. On the other hand

```
stream = OpenRead["!notepad.exe"]
Print["next"]
```

the `Print` is evaluated right after the first line and we get back the cursor. The `stream` of course could only be closed if the Notepad window is closed, so the next example causes *Mathematica* to wait, and only the first `Print` is printed before closing Notepad:

```
stream = OpenRead["!notepad.exe"]
Print["next"]
Close@stream
Print["more"]
```

Comment: It doesn't appear something like the following would work `ReadList["!cmd /k \"node -p \"console.log('test');\"", String]` or with Cygwin `ReadList["!\"C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe\" -c \"echo test\"", String]`.  Are you aware of the reason why?

Answer (score 6):

```
Table[Pause[1/2]; Import["!dir","Text"];, {3}];
```

Import can also be used to pipe command line output straight into Mathematica.

```
<<"!dir"
```

Also works.