# can't start r process in cmd

Tags: interoperability, command-line, rlink, run

```
process=StartProcess[$SystemShell];
outputFile=FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[],"output.txt"}];
ClearAll[run];
run[commands_,seconds_:2]:=Module[{},
    commandSent=commands<>" > \""<>outputFile<>"\"";
    WriteLine[process,commandSent];
    Pause[seconds];
    Import[outputFile]
];

$rDirectory="C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.3.0\\bin\\x64";
```

now runnning

```
run["cd \""<>$rDirectory<>"\""]
```

and

```
run["dir"]
```

produces the same result as running on cmd directly but running

```
run["R.exe"]
```

doesn't seem to start the R process. But if i do these directly on cmd it works.

I have used this method several times to connect to external processes but it is not working for R. Someone please help!!!

Comment: `Run` is for single execution while i want to keep sending a sequence of commands programmatically and retrieve results. Can you please check whether i am the only one having this problem or there is some issue?

Comment: Oh sorry. Forget about what I said. I thought it was about a typo...

Comment: But you might be interested in [`RLink`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/RLink/guide/RLink.html)...

Comment: Stupid `RLink` crashes for large data. And has other bugs. I want the program to run in R but queries generated programmatically since there are alot of combinations.

Comment: Do i need to add it to "PATH" since i am `cd`-ing to the directory which has the executable?

Comment: `process=StartProcess[$SystemShell];` is starting the cmd not as an admin. Do you know how to start the process as an admin?

Comment: If you don't mind the notebook being your terminal, you may try `Import[commandstring,"Text"]`, e.g., `cmdstr = "!R.exe something"`, then `Import[cmdstr,"Text"]`

Comment: @xieyn does your command work for windows? It is not working for me.

Comment: Does anyone know how to get the process object of a running process like a running cmd. Which will allow me to run R explicitly there and send commands via the process object.

Comment: Perhaps make a post for `RLink` crashing with large data.  That should return some useful results for half of this question.

Comment: @user13892 Ah, it's weird. `Import` is not working  with R. I had used `Import` to call another external program and it worked perfectly. `RunProcess`  works for me, for example, `RunProcess[{"c:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.5.1\\bin\\Rscript.exe", 
  "test.r"}, "StandardOutput"]`, but this may be not what you want...

Comment: *"`RLink` crashes for large data. And has other bugs."* - Can you please report those? Either through the standard mechanism (tech.support), or even just via separate questions here. There are some bugs for the installation procedure, that are being dealt with, but I have not seen reports for crashing with big data transfers yet. Thanks.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I will create a concrete example for RLink failing with a dataset and add as a separate question. But can you please help me why this simple approach of calling R from cmd running as a subprocess of the wolfram kernel is not working here.

Comment: Thanks. Re: command shell - off the top of my head, you need an extra "!" sign in front of your command if you use `Import`, see e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6876/calling-external-commands-without-showing-command-prompt-on-windows) for more details. If that doesn't help, I can try looking into this later.