# Import multiple files from folder in order of date added

Tags: import, sorting

I have a folder that contains certain files I want to import. In my case those are .png files. As all the files I want to import contain the phrase "accum" in their filenames, I can use

```
SetDirectory[directory]; (*directory is string of the directory that contains the files*)
importString = "./*" <> "accum" <> "*";
files = Import[importString];
```

to obtain a list consisting of all the images I wanted to import. Of course this list is sorted by filename.
What can I do to tell `Import` that the files should not be sorted by "name" but by other options like "date added" (which is what I want)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Likely something like the following:

```
Import[#, "PNG"] & /@ SortBy[FileNames[importString], FileDate[#,"Creation"]&]
```

although I suspect there might be a more terse approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this.  You may need to adapt it.

```
ls = Import["!ls -al 2>&1", "Text"];
lines = Rest@StringSplit[ls, "\n"];
parts = StringSplit /@ lines;
dates = parts[[All, 6 ;; 8]];
names = parts[[All, 9]];
datedfiles = DeleteCases[MapThread[Prepend, {dates, names}], {"." | "..", _}];
Column[datedfiles]
```

> {"ans.png", "Jan", "22", "23:53"}
>
> {"curve1.png", "Jan", "5", "00:44"}
>
> {"data.sav", "Jun", "20", "2013"}
>
> {"test.mx", "May", "1", "2013"}

This list can then be processed and the files imported as required.

**Additional Note**

Timings to find the name of the most recent file in a large directory of files.

This is pretty much instant :

```
StringDrop[Part[Rest@
   StringSplit[Import["!dir /od /a:-d 2>&1", "Text"], "\n"], -3], 36]
```

But this is very slow :

```
Last@SortBy[FileNames[], FileDate[#, "Creation"] &]
```

Comment: Caveat: will not work on your average Windows machine.

Comment: Yes, use `Import["!dir 2>&1", "Text"]` on Windows, and extract parts accordingly.

Comment: Good method (+1) but consider using: `ReadList["!dir /od /a:-d 2>&1", String]` -- see e.g. [(2401)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2401)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - ah yes, `Last@ReadList["!dir /od /a-d /b", String]`