# Get names of all folders in a directory

Tags: files-and-directories

I simply want a list of the folder names (without subfolders) in a directory, but can't seem to find the right command for this. Can anyone help me out :)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This topic covers your question: [2388](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2388/5478)

Comment: ah sorry I didn't see this thread

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[]
Select[
 FileNames[],
 DirectoryQ]
```

Comment: +1, I forgot there's a `DirectoryQ`

Comment: @rasher thanks, do you think it should be a duplicate of the quesiton I've linked?

Comment: Yup.... that link fits the bill.