# How to get only the directories (not the files) inside the current directory?

Tags: files-and-directories

`FileNames[]` lists all the files and directories inside the current one. How can I list only the directories?

Comment: @Kuba I just discovered that. Thanks.

Comment: more general: [2388](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2388/5478)

Comment: @Kuba That's not more general, it's a different problem. Here I want to list only the directories inside the current one, without going recursively into deeper levels.

Comment: @becko I didn't notice your comment before closing, but really I think it's the same problem with slightly different parameters, and your self-answer shows just this.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think it's a related, but still different problem. I was just facing the same problem now, and I had forgotten I had asked this question before. I almost posted a new question because I could not find this one, probably because it was closed. I'd reconsider reopening.

Answer (score 2):

I just found one way to do it:

```
Select[FileNames[], DirectoryQ]
```