# FileNames[] output: directories from files?

Tags: files-and-directories

In the output from FileNames[], how do I distinguish directories from files?

Comment: Check `DirectoryQ` and see: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2388/5478, is that enough?

Comment: You can use that in conjunction with `Select[]` of course.

Comment: @Kuba, yes thank you