# How can I return only folders when using FileNames[...]

Tags: files-and-directories

If we want to see what is contained with a directory we simply go:

```
FileNames[]
```

and this will list everything in the current directory. If we want to filter, for example we only want to see .csv files we can then say:

```
FileNames["*.csv"]
```

So filtering is fine if one has a key on which to filter, like a file extension or a naming convention.

If I want to only return the folders in a given directory, how would I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate: [List all the directories under the current one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2388/125)?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2401/68689 from @kglr 's link.

Comment: Quite right, I'll add an answer but I will also mark as duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the users in the comments:

`Select[FileNames[],DirectoryQ]`